# LINQ query (group by groups of items)

Tags: c#, linq

I have a little problem. I have database table with some indicators which look like:
[image: DB Table]

I want to obtain list of RED groups and finally get the begin and the end of each group (that's the simpliest part). Do you have any idea how to do this?

Comment: Is that your entire table (width-wise)?

Comment: Do you have more info on the data in your database which you want to filter?

Comment: Is there any reason that you have to do this with a linq query or any other way would be acceptable?

Comment: IMHO RDBMS systems (and LINQ for that matter) are not a good fit for this type of data manipulation. You might be better off iterating manually.

Comment: It doesn't matter what schema, what table or whatever in database it is. It must be done by LINQ and on column which contains ONLY NUMBERS. In this column (name it **Indicator**) i have four values 1,2,3,4. I have to group them only by value 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this extension method to create sequence groups which satisfy your predicate

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GroupBySequence<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    var iterator = source.GetEnumerator();
    List<T> group = new List<T>();
    while (iterator.MoveNext())
    {
        if (predicate(iterator.Current))
        {
            group.Add(iterator.Current);
            continue;
        }            

        if (group.Any())
        {                    
            yield return group;
            group = new List<T>();
        }
    }

    if (group.Any())
        yield return group;
}
```

Usage:

```
int[] data = { 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1 };
var groups = data.GroupBySequence(i => i == 2); // returns [2] and [2,2,2]
```

Comment: Not as good as I wanted, but this will be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: @Fka I changed implementation to return sequences by condition (instead of separator). Because you have mentioned that there is four possible values in column, so I think you need only values of `2`. BTW you can't do that on server side

Comment: Thank you. I can't do that on server side becouse application has to use existing resources which cannot be changed. Thank you so much! Big beer from me! (or vodka as you wish :P, we're not living so far from each other)